# How do I get the correct subnode with elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, multidimensional-array

I am trying to get specific parts of the data back from a specific document. The document contains product information. This is just a small snippet of the document to explain it better.

```
"_source": {
    "product": {
        "code": "AM109",
        "stuff": "98989",
        "languages": [
            {
                "language": "en",
                "labels": {
                    "name": "Fusce nulla augue",
                    "description": "Cras ultricies diam vel orci feugiat ornare. Nulla convallis ligula quis fringilla suscipit. Proin malesuada ligula enim, sit amet semper lorem imperdiet in."
                }
            },
            {
                "language": "es",
                "labels": {
                    "name": "Aliquam ut odio quam",
                    "description": "Nulla pulvinar tortor eu ex vestibulum, nec dictum diam tristique. Pellentesque vitae nibh diam. In id purus at sapien eleifend pulvinar non at velit."
                }
            }
    }
}
```

The document contains different information for different countries, and labels for different languages. To explain I use the labels. 
I need to get the information of the correct product based on the code (product.code), and for the languages it should already only return the labels in the language as requested. E.g. if language es is requested:

```
"_source": {
    "product": {
        "code": "AM109",
        "stuff": "98989",
        "languages": [
            {
                "language": "es",
                "labels": {
                    "name": "Aliquam ut odio quam",
                    "description": "Nulla pulvinar tortor eu ex vestibulum, nec dictum diam tristique. Pellentesque vitae nibh diam. In id purus at sapien eleifend pulvinar non at velit."
                }
            }
    }
}
```

I have tried this with nested options and filters, but I cannot get the correct data returned.

This is an existing system so I cannot make changes to the structure, but I can change the mapping if needed and repopulate the index.

Who can help me with this?

Comment: Can you show the query you've tried so far? Also can you show the mapping of the `languages` field?

Comment: You would need to change the way you index your documents, depending on your needs:
#1: do you need to support a fixed set of languages and do all your products have labels and descriptions in all languages?
#2: do you need to return results in multiple languages (for one request)?

Comment: @DanielSchneiter #1: Yes, all products have the same labels and descriptions in all languages. #2: Only a single language has to be returned in one request, based on a parameter in the request.

Answer (score 0):

As all documents come with information about all languages and you only search in one language at a given time I suggest the following approach:

1. Store your documents in language specific indices (advantage: same field names)
2. You can send your documents always to the same index, but define an ingest pipeline which appends a language-specific suffix such as "_en" to your `_index`-field, to get your document routed/stored in the language-specific index
3. Adjust your query to only query the index containing the language

If the last step is not possible, you could define an alias, pointing to all language-specific indices and in your query filter on a field, containing the language-code

Comment: The issue is that I have to make an extension to an existing system/ES. So I cannot change the structure of the index radically because than the existing bits will fail.

Comment: Please share the mapping and the query you tried so far